# Proof of the 2 pointer method for finding a linked list loop

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory

The linked list with a loop problem is classical - "how do you detect that a linked list has a loop" ? The "creative" solution to this is to use 2 pointers, one moving at a speed of 1 and the second one at the speed of 2. If the two pointers meet then there is a loop.

How do you prove this mathematically and more importantly how do you generalize? For example, will having the first pointer at a speed of 2 and the second at the speed of 3 still work?

For those without a background in CS, a linked list is a collection of nodes, each node has a link to the next one. So you can only go forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a loop (of $n$ nodes), then once a pointer has entered the loop it will remain there forever; so we can move forward in time until both pointers are in the loop. From here on the pointers can be represented by integers modulo $n$ with initial values $a$ and $b$. The condition for them to meet after $t$ steps is then

$a + t \equiv b + 2t \text{ mod }n$

which has solution $t = a - b \text{ mod }n$.

This will work so long as the difference between the speeds shares no prime factors with $n$.

Comment: I'm curious how the math works to get from the first equation to the second one.  I'm unfamiliar with modular arithmetic.

Comment: @sourcedelica: modular arithmetic - just subtract $t+b$ from both sides.

Comment: oh, is it  `t ≡ a - b (mod n)`?  I was curious because it went from congruence `≡` to equals `=`, so I was reading it as `t = a - (b % n)`.

Comment: @sourcedelica: It's been a while, not sure what I originally intended by the notation. It's true no matter how you interpret it (since the solutions are cyclic mod n). Choosing `(a-b)%n` probably makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: The distance between pointers is increased by $1$ each step. The single restriction on speeds is that their diference should be coprime with the loop's length.

Answer (score 2):

Say, there are $l$ elements before the cycle, and the cycle has $n$ elements. We will use two references $R_p$ and $R_q$ which take $p$ and $q$ steps in each iteration; $p > q$. In the Floyd's algorithm, $p = 2, q = 1$.

For any $i$, we can find the "index" (position) at which we reach after taking $i$ steps from the head. So index ranges from 0 to $l+n-1$. We can prove that for any $i \ge l$, the index is:

$l + (i-l) \bmod n$

So, after $s$ iterations, $R_p$ and $R_q$ will meet iff:
(assuming $qs \ge l$ and so $ps \ge l$ also)

$l + (ps − l) \bmod n = l + (qs − l) \bmod n$

$\Leftrightarrow ((p − q)s) \bmod n = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow (p − q)s = \text{a multiple of } n$

For any given $p$ and $q$ with $p > q$, we can find $s$ satisfying above (e.g. $s$ = a multiple of $n$). So we can conclude that $R_p$ and $R_q$ will always meet after some number of iterations.

You may refer [this article](https://mathsanew.com/articles/cycle_detection.pdf) (written by me) for more background; section "Other Step-Counts for References".

Comment: Is there a way to find the limit on the number of iterations, assuming p = 2 and q = 1? Would the maximum be two iterations?